# What is the conversion rate per product this year

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to show product and its conversion rate.  See below query, not sure if my conversion portion of orders/sessions is correct. The products table only contains id, and name. Open to any feedback.

*Edit: Conversion Rate is defined as visitors to the blog who purchased a product

Tables:

Purchases
[image]

Traffic_events_atl
[image]

Question: What is the conversion rate per product in 2020?

```
SELECT 
  pr.name as product_name, -- per product
  (COUNT(DISTINCT p.visitor_id)/COUNT(DISTINCT t.visit_id))*100 as Conv_Pct -- orders/session 
FROM
  purchases p
JOIN products pr
ON p.product_id = pr.id
JOIN traffic_events_atl t
ON t.visitor_id = p.visitor_id
WHERE DATEPART('year',timestamp) = 2020 -- this year
AND t.property ilike '%blog%' -- blog specific websites
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Define "conversion rate" based on your data.

Comment: Conversion Rate in this sense I would want visitors to the blog who purchased a product

Comment: Added sample table and data